# Rails model sub folder namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

If I have a sub folder models/crms with a model

```
class class Crms::Document < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "documents"
end
```

It doesn't resolve ApplicationRecord as it in the parent folder.  So how do I reference the class in the main folder from a sub folder please?

Comment: Is the first line literally `class class ...`? Because there's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to define this is:

```
# app/models/crms/document.rb
module Crms
  class Document < ::ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "documents"
  end
end
```

You're writing `class class`. And:

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
>   nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
>   constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
>   module nesting at the point of definition.
>   - [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition)